# ng-click is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, x-editable

I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days and I couldn't locate its core so any help on the matter is really appreciated.

I was creating a form that was inline editable with xeditable and the edit(save/cancel) buttons were working as expected but the DELETE button is not calling the given method from the controller. I tried placing it on other parts in the code both as a button and a link  and ng-click was not working both ways! I'm quite new at Angular so any debugging tips on how to solve this kinds of problems are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Here is the code from the app file:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ["Controllers", "xeditable"])

   app.run(function (editableOptions) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
   });
```

Here is the code for the controller (in different .js file from app.js)

```
angular.module("Controllers", [])
.controller("controller", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.users= {};
//get display data
$http.get("/User/All").success(function (data) {
    $scope.users= data;
});

//form methods

$scope.editUser = function (data, id) {
    edit_data.UserID = id;
    $http.post("/User/Edit", edit_data).success(function () {
        angular.extend(data, { id: id });
    });
};

$scope.deleteUser = function (index, id) {
    $http.post("/User/Delete", id).success(function() {
        $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
    });
  };
}]);
```

Here is the code from the form:

```
<container ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Surname
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>
            <span editable-text="user.Name" e-name="Name" e-form="rowform" e-required>
                {{user.Name}}
            </span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <span editable-text="user.Surname" e-name="Surname" e-form="rowform" e-required>
                {{user.Surname}}
            </span>

        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
            <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="editUser($data, user.UserID)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == user">
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
                    save
                </button>
                <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
                    cancel
                </button>
            </form>
            <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteUser($index,user.UserID)">delete</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Is `$scope.deleteUser` being called? Set a breakpoint in the method. Or add a console.log statement.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg At first it gave me a POST http://localhost:13761/User/Delete 500 (Internal Server Error) which I know is a serverside problem, so I rechecked the api call method and it exists defined with [HttpPost] specification(in asp mvc) etc. Since this wasn't logical because I have almost identical call for Edit and it works, I tried adding another method to the button which only sets $scope.var and that was the case when it didnt get invoked. I noticed that this kinds of methods couldn't be called even in a <a> tag. I'm really struggling with both the 500 Error and the method calls.

Comment: you aren't passing object to `$post` for the data which means you aren't sending key/value pair. Inspect the actual request in network tab of browser console to confirm

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sending the id parameter as a data to $post and I get the 500 internal server error on click

Comment: but post data requires a key and a value, not just a value. You should have object as argument. No serrver code provided to help with that end

Comment: UPDATE: i had a small misspell of method name locally and it gave me the 500 error now that it was fixed I came to the mode where the request is NOT executed and there are no logs besides the GET calls in the console

Comment: @charlietfl  THANK you so much ! That was the problem to the 500 error :) And the problem where the button didn't react on new methods was cause the javascript files were cached ( it worked in incognito mode) :)